# get specific value from http response

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using `requests` library to query a F5 Big IP. I get the list of Virtual Server. I need to do a loop  to get each VS name `(VS1, VS2, VS3)` from the response  to use in another request  like

```
https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual/VS1
```

What code will get each name value from the response? I tried [this](https://realpython.com/python-json/#serializing-json) but could not get it to work.

```
url = "https://bigipname.domain.local/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual"
querystring = {"$select":"name"}
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Accept': "*/*",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Host': "bigipgname.domain.local",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False)
```

I get the response in the following json format :

```
{'kind': 'tm:ltm:virtual:virtualcollectionstate', 'selfLink': 'https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/virtual?$select=name&ver=13.1.1.2', 'items': [{'name': 'VS1'}, {'name': 'VS2'}, {'name': 'VS3'}]}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That response is not JSON, that's a Python dict.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to extract the "items".

```
new_list = [item["name"] for item in response["items"]]
```

Comment: Hello  everyone      Stuck again         I use   the following code